# Copy files and folders by specific days of the month

Tags: windows-server-2003, batch-file, robocopy, xcopy

I'd like to create a batch file to copy the files and folders by specific days. For example, 15th and 30th of the month(not 15th to 30th) copy the files and folder to another location. How can I write this script with `xcopy` or `robocopy` utility?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below command in a text file:

```
robocopy sourcePath destinationPath *.* /e /r:0 /w:0 /np
```

Then save the text file and change the file to `cmd` file.

After that, you can create a scheduled task and configure it to run in 15th and 30th every month (on `Trigger` tab). You can add the above command in the `Actions` tab.

Comment: I have windows server 2003 in my network. I don't think robocopy work in the windows server 2003. Also, I don't want to copy all of the files and folders.

Comment: Please clarify your question. you said `with xcopy or robocopy` and you didn't say which OS that you have used, however, you can download the `Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools` and use it to achieve `robocopy`. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657

Comment: If you wouldn't like to copy all files you can put your file name instead of `*.*` for more information about `robocopy` syntax please refer to this link. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Comment: Thanks Tom for your time, Can I do that without using scheduled task and I specify that log the event every time copies done?

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: @fedora, It's another question and it's better to ask it separately.

Comment: @fedora, you need a script to be run on schedule. This is *exactly* what Windows Task Scheduler exists for and it's really quite good at it. If you are up for a Linux analogy (given your name/avatar), Scheduler is basically a crond on steroids.